# AWS CDK - get ProvisioningArtifactIds from ServiceCatalog product

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-cdk

In CDK I couldn't find from documentation how I can get `ProvisioningArtifactIds` e.g. `pa-4abcdjnxjj6ne`? CloudFormation will return the value, but not CDK.

(**Edit**: in CF, `ProductId: !Ref Product` and `ProvisioningArtifactId: !GetAtt Product.ProvisioningArtifactIds`)

I need it, so I can make a [CloudFormation Product](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_servicecatalog/CloudFormationProduct.html)

```py
    product = aws_servicecatalog.CloudFormationProduct(self, "Product",
    product_name="My Product",
    owner="Product Owner",
    product_versions=[servicecatalog.CloudFormationProductVersion(
        product_version_name="v1",
        cloud_formation_template=servicecatalog.CloudFormationTemplate.from_product_stack(S3BucketProduct(self, "S3BucketProduct"))
    )])
```

and later in the same stack make the [association](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_servicecatalog/CfnServiceActionAssociation.html)

```py
    aws_servicecatalog.CfnServiceActionAssociation(
            self,
            "serviceId",
            product_id=product.product_id,
            provisioning_artifact_id="????", # ????
            service_action_id=myServiceAction.attr_id,
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CloudFormation docs list the [return values](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-servicecatalog-cloudformationproduct.html#aws-resource-servicecatalog-cloudformationproduct-return-values) for the resource.

The `!Ref Product` value is easy.  The CDK [source code](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/74318c7d22bfc00de9e005f68a0a6aaa58c7db39/packages/%40aws-cdk/aws-servicecatalog/lib/product.ts#L193) shows it is exposed directly on the L2 `CloudFormationProduct` as `product_id`.

```py
# !Ref Product
ref = product.product_id
```

The `!GetAtt Product.ProvisioningArtifactIds` value is trickier.  First reference the underlying L1 `CfnCloudFormationProduct` construct with [escape hatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cfn_layer.html#cfn_layer_cfn) syntax.  Then call `get_att`:

```py
# !GetAtt Product.ProvisioningArtifactIds
cfn_product = product.node.default_child
get_att = cfn_product.get_att("ProvisioningArtifactIds")
```

Comment: sorry, a little bit lost, `product.product_id` return like `prod-abcdzk7xy33qa` and not `pa-xxxxx`, ah you mean as I am using the L1 return the `pa-xxx` ? if yes then how can I get `prod-xxx`?

Comment: @GeoCom I know nothing about the Service Catalog API.  I simply read the source code and docs.  How would you get the value with CloudFormation?

Comment: in CF, `ProductId: !Ref Product` and `ProvisioningArtifactId: !GetAtt Product.ProvisioningArtifactIds`